# node.js: How to use passport with koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, koa

Passport's website claims

> Passport can be unobtrusively dropped in to any Express-based web
>   application.

Can I use it with Koa as well? If so, what would be a good starting point to learn how to do so? I am thinking about a classic username/password strategy using sessions (maybe with Redis).

Please excuse this stupid question, I'm just getting started with Node and there are too many things to learn at once and my head is spinning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried this ?

[koa-passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-passport)

Comment: No. But I will now :)

Comment: @ØleBjarnstroem you should probably mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: its the correct answer, its works well

Answer (score 0):

plz check this link 
https://github.com/mapmeld/koa-passport-example/
https://blog.risingstack.com/tag/koajs/
http://knowthen.com/episode-3-koajs-quickstart-guide/[enter link description here](http://knowthen.com/episode-3-koajs-quickstart-guide/)